# Can you ID this part?

Tags: part-identification

[image: reference image]

I am trying to id the three grey bars on the left-hand side of the image.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [32294 Wishbone Suspension Arm](http://brickset.com/parts?query=32294):

[image: 32294]

This is listed as part x136 on Bricklink.